# Rectangles in a modified chessboard

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of rectangles in a chessboard with the diagonal unit squares removed(of the 4 corner unit squares, two were removed which were diagonal)? I tried counting but it was becoming difficult. The rectangles which have the corner squares are difficult for me to count. Also, the source is asking for exact answer, where I think I make mistakes, please help. Thanks.

Comment: So you removed $10$ tiles in total?

Comment: Both diagonals?  Then 16 squares were removed.

Comment: but then he says of the 4 corner unit squares two where removed, perhaps that means only one of the diagonals is removed?

Comment: If it is exactly $2$ opposite corner squares removed, count rectangles without restriction, and subtract the number of rectangles that involve $1$ or both corner squares. Neither count should be hard.

Comment: I am having problems with the number of rectangles that involve 1 or both corner squares. How do I do that? Could you please write a detailed solution? Thanks.

Comment: Are there any restriction on the size of the rectangles? I mean, are squares counting?

Comment: No, squares will be counted.

Comment: Good question. Yeah, counting is a problem for me too.

Comment: I still don't get if just two opposite corner are removed or a whole main diagonal, splitting the chessboard in two connected components.

Comment: What's a rectangle?  Just the four corners, or the corners plus the sides?  In the former case the rectangles can straddle the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

The number of rectangles in an ordinary $8\times8$ board is

$$(1+2+\cdots+8)^2=36^2=1296$$

The number of such rectangles that include the upper lefthand corner square is

$$8\cdot8=64$$

and likewise for rectangles that include the bottom righthand corner square.  There is only one rectangle (namely the entire board) that includes both those squares.  Thus the number of rectangles that include *neither* of the two opposite corner squares is

$$1296-(64+64)+1=1169$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the removed squares are `a8,b7,c6,d5,e4,f3,g2,h1` then the chessboard is partitioned in two connected components and any rectangle may lie just in the lower left or in the upper right triangle. So we count the number of rectangles in the lower left triangle accordingly to the position of the upper right corner of the rectangle. For instance, assuming that the upper right corner falls in `a7`, then we have $7$ choices for the rectangle. Assuming that the upper right corner falls in `b6`, then we have $2\cdot 6$ choices. This gives that the total number of rectangles is given by:

$$ 2\sum_{j=1}^{7}\sum_{k=1}^{8-j}jk=\sum_{j=1}^{7}j(9-j)(8-j)=\color{red}{420}. $$